# Get enclosure fields from RSS with XmlNodeList

Tags: c#, xml

I'm trying to make an app for Windows Store get RSS feed from a web site.
Here is the RSS source:

```
> <title> some data </title>
    >     <description> some desc </description> 
    >     <link>http://www.****.com</link>
    >     <pubDate>Fri, 21 Jun 2013 19:30:48</pubDate>
    >     <guid>ttp://www.****.com</guid>
    >     <enclosure url= "http://www.***.com//images/332010.jpg " length="5000" type="image/jpge"/>
```

And the code to read from it:

```
 XmlDocument RSSXml = await XmlDocument.LoadFromUriAsync(new Uri(uri));
            XmlNodeList xmlUrl = RSSXml.GetElementsByTagName("enclosure");
            XmlNodeList RSSNodeList = RSSXml.SelectNodes("rss/channel/item");
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (var RSSNode in RSSNodeList)
            {
                var RSSSubNode = RSSNode.SelectSingleNode("title");
                string title = RSSSubNode != null ? RSSSubNode.InnerText : "";
                RSSSubNode = RSSNode.SelectSingleNode("link");
                string link = RSSSubNode != null ? RSSSubNode.InnerText : "";
                RSSSubNode = RSSNode.SelectSingleNode("enclosure");
                string desc = RSSSubNode != null ? RSSSubNode.InnerText : "";
             }
             Label.Text = sb.ToString();
```

It all works fine expect for "enclosure" value, I need to get the "url" value and I tried a lot of formats but didn't get any thing and some times get errors.
Any help.

Comment: Don't you want RSSSubNode.Attributes["url"].Value instead of RSSSubNode.InnerText for the enclosure node?

Comment: @ppejovic There is no System.ServiceModel.Syndication in W8 store apps just Windows.Web.Syndication and this one doesn't accept XmlReader.Creat(uri) as param.

Comment: @svinja I want the value of "url" from "enclosure".

Comment: Yes I understand that, but you seem to be reading InnerText instead of the "url" attribute value from it.

Comment: What should I do exactly?